# Compiled SASS into CSS is not showing my images or fonts

Tags: css, image, sass, fonts

So I compiled my SASS into one CSS file using codekit 2 on their own localhost and the website looks perfectly fine.

However when I upload my website onto a webserver (including all my SASS and CSS) it will not show some of my images.  Then when I remove the SASS from my server leaving the compiles CSS it looses my fonts as well.

Does anyone know why is this?

Here is the website: http://bubbacue.nathanpatton.co.uk/

And the GitHub Repo for all the files: https://github.com/NathanPatton/Bubbacue

Comment: Probably because the images/fonts are not in the location you specified.  Sass has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @cimmanon the location of the images have not changed and it works fine on the localhost.

Comment: Ya... this is not a Sass issue, unless you also forgot to import certain Sass partials.  The Sass files being on the server have zero to do with your issue.

Comment: If the Sass isn't the problem @SeanStopnik what is?

Comment: My guess is that you have your file path set to the root, and since you are using a subdomain, the path is incorrect.  Try changing your file path to a relative path like `../` to be sure you are pointing to the right spot.

Comment: @NathanPatton How can you think Sass has anything to do with the problem when all it does is generate your CSS?  The Sass code is never sent to the browser because browsers don't have a Sass interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web host is generating a bunch of `403 Forbidden` and `404 Not Found` errors on the assets.

In Chrome, go to View, Developer, JavaScript Console and you'll see a list of the problem files and directories. [Here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1905/Why+am+I+seeing+a+403+Forbidden+error+message%3F#gs) is how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks I was able to change my file permissions on my images in my FTP client for some reason they where only set to the user.  Thanks again.